# PySpark when/otherwise multiple conditions

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Have a dataframe that I'm filtering out on some specific conditions.  The results which are either a 1 or 0 based on the filtering condition.  Previously this would work if I split the dataframe only looking for matches.  I decided to change it up a bit and would like **all** the results and the ability to flag them appropriately.  Here's a small example of what I tried.

```
matches = df.withColumn('MATCHES', f.when(
                   ((df.NAME >= 0.9) & (df.STREET >= 0.7) & (sdf.STREETNUM >= 0.7))
                                 |
                   ((df.PHONE == 1) & (sdf.NAME == 1) & (df.STREET == 1) & (df.CITY == 1) & (df.STREETNUM == 1)), 1).otherwise(0))
```

Every record that goes through this job should have either a 1 or 0 attached in a new column.  1's are matches, and 0's are not.  For example:  Input file has 50,000 records, I would expect 50,000 results each with a 0 or 1.  When I previously had this code block do a simple filter with just the compound conditions, I would get roughly 2500 1's which is correct.  Adding the withColumn/when/otherwise components to this has changed my result set I can't understand why since the conditions and input files did not change.  E.g., output now has 4 1's, and 2400 0's. Previously there was 2500 1's and the rest would be 0's.

Expected Results would be something like

```
+------+------+------------+------------+------------+-------+
|NAME  |PHONE |STREET      |STREETNUM   |CITY        |MATCHES|
+------+------+------------+------------+------------+-------+
|.97   |  .94 |      .88   |     .77    |    .99     |   1   |
|.43   |  .78 |      .76   |     .87    |    .64     |   0   |
|.62   |  .21 |      .98   |     .50    |    .02     |   0   |
|.78   |  .96 |      .11   |     .10    |    .05     |   0   |
|.99   |  .99 |      .99   |     .99    |    .99     |   1   |
+------+------+------------+------------+------------+-------+
```

Comment: What does your result look like? Can you paste the DataFrame? That way it would be tad easier to be on the same page IMHO.

Comment: What do you mean by `I'm severely truncating my expected result sets` here?

Comment: Added details for clarification

Comment: Do you by any chance have missing values/`Null` in the data?

Comment: I do and I did think about this.  I'm filling the frame on filtered values before the subset to see if this corrects things.

Comment: @cph_sto I figured it out.  Previous to filtering, I'm doing a join operation that is one to many.  So, while a record, ABC be be a match to a record I'm matching against, it will have many more non-matches.  After the filtering I'm calling a dropDuplicates on the data frame.  The rub, I'm droping matches now.  I'll have to think of a way to grab all matches and then basically say, if you're a match, you can't be a non-match and THEN drop duplicates.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188037/discussion-between-datadog-and-cph-sto).

Comment: That’s great that you found the error. All the best.